# ASP.Net MVC MapRoute problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, url-routing

There seem to be a lot of issues on SO dealing with MapRoute problems. I've read through a bunch of them, but I can't see what I'm doing wrong in my implementation. I've got the following routes set up:

```
routes.MapRoute( _
    "FilesDisplay", _
    "{controller}/{action}/{year}/{month}", _
    New With {.controller = "Files", .action = "Display", .year = "", .month = ""})

routes.MapRoute( _
    "Default", _
    "{controller}/{action}", _
    New With {.controller = "Files", .action = "Index"})
```

and the following RouteLink:

```
<%=Html.RouteLink("Show", "FilesDisplay", New With {.year = 2008, .month = 5})%>
```

However, the resulting URL for "Show" is /Files/Index/2008/5. Why is it picking up the Index action instead of the Display action?

**Edit:** As a lark I changed the second route to `.action = "Display"` just to see if I could get the URL to change, and it **still** resolves to /Files/Index/2008/5.

**Edit 2:** I also tried:

```
<%=Html.ActionLink("Show", "Display", "Files", New With {.year = 2008, .month = 5}, Nothing)%>
```

but that also resolves to /Files/Index/2008/5. Why is it that no matter what I specify for an action it's defaulting to Index?

Comment: What version of ASP.NET MVC are you running on? There was a problem with RouteLinks whereby you had to explicitly state the controller and action in one of the releases.

Comment: I believe this is RC1 (where can I check to be sure?).

Comment: I think it displays in your program list under the control panel. I don't think you can have more than one version installed.

Comment: It reads "Microsoft ASP.NET MVC RC", so I assume that's RC1.

Comment: what version of IIS are you running?

Comment: This is running out of the VS Dev server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to MVC RC 1.0 seemed to fix ActionLink but not RouteLink. Therefore I'm moving forward with ActionLink. I'd love to know why RouteLink doesn't want to work though.